# Retrieving a line of text splited in 2 or more Strings

Tags: java, string

I want to retrieve the info of a line of text from a textfile in 2 different strings...

This is the situation, getting the password line from pwd.txt :

```
String pwdRetrieved = retreivePwd.getPwd("pwd.txt");
```

However the password is crypted and it needs 2 valors, the password itself + a "key", like this:

```
4B5CB9348D5ADB733D43C2FB57A6A971-admin_pwd
```

`admin_pwd` is the "key" or "reference" to the encrypted password.

Now what I want to do is get `4B5CB9348D5ADB733D43C2FB57A6A971` into a string and `admin_pwd` into another string, is that possible?

More specific, i want to read from the `.txt` until the character "-" is found and store it into a String, then i want it to keep reading after "-" and store it into another string.

Comment: Read the whole string and then split it by ("-"). You will get a string array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the whole string, split on the "-" and retrieve the two parts from the created array:

```
String pwdRetrieved = retreivePwd.getPwd("pwd.txt"); 
String[] splitPwdRetrieved = pwdRetrieved.split("-");

String password = splitPwdRetrieved[0];
String key = splitPwdRetrieved[1];
```

Comment: Oh my god, didnt fall on that xD ... many thanks worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
String[] pwd = pwdRetrieved.split("-");
```

After you can split this array value into individual strings.

Answer (score 1):

Using String's split method will do the trick:

```
String[] split = pwdRetrieved.split("-");
```

Will return a string array with the two strings you are after

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] split = pwdRetrieved.split("-");
String enc=split[0];
String pass=split[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

you could split your String at the `-` after reading the whole line like this:

```
String pwdRetrieved = retreivePwd.getPwd("pwd.txt"); 
String[] split = pwdRetrieved .split("-");
System.out.println(split[0]);
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
String[] parts = pwdRetrieved.split("-");
String password = parts[0];
String key = parts[1];
```

Or do this:

```
int dashPosition = pwdRetrieved.indexOf("-");
String password = pwdRetrieved.substring(0, dashPosition);
String key = pwdRetrieved.substring(dashPosition + 1);
```